# How to detect collisions in java

Tags: java, jframe, collision

I'm working on a game for [this](https://itch.io/jam/metroidvania-month-17) game jam. I'm making it in java because I can't be bothered to learn a game engine. I'm using JFrame as my graphics library, and I can't think of a way to detect collisions between my player and the 2d world. Here's the link to the github page: https://github.com/DJPretzel-bit64/UnderAdventure.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to represent your actors with the implementation of `java.awt.Shape` (say `Rectanlge2D`). That implementation would have `boolean intersects(Rectangle2D r)` already implemented for you.

So your job would be to pre-filter shapes so that they are reasonably close to your target actor, predict a move of those candidates and test for intersections if they would be at predicted points.

Answer (score 0):

First make a rectangle and surround your object with it (like a collision box) then repeat this for all of your objects
then just check using rect.intersects(rect)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).